# Can I use "Where" block and helper methods at the same time in spock

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, spock

I have a specification which essentially looks like this:

```
def "my example specification"(){
given:"some mocked object which depends on a object created in the where clause"
        def display = mockDisplay()

and:"a activityt"
        def activity = new ConfigActivity(display)
when:
        activity.doStuff()
then:
        1 * display.select()

where:
        dependency << new Dependency()
}


private mockDisplay() {
        def display = Mock(ConfigActivity.Display)
        display.addDependency(dependency)
        return display
}
```

I understand that that the "mockDisplay()" method is out of scope from the "where" clause. However since a few specifications tend to get rather cluttered with boilerplate code (not in this over simplified example offcourse) I really need some way to reuse my "given" statements and in doing so I would really like to make use of the Spock "where" clauses as well.

Is this doable? Or is there another way to go about this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no magic way to access a data variable from a helper method, but you can pass it as a method parameter.

Comment: If I just change the private mockDisplay() method signature to private mockDisplay(dependency) it would work? I will give it a try..

Comment: You'll have to adapt both the method declaration and the caller.

Comment: Yep thats right, the compiler kind of helpt me with that one though :)